# how to put 5 texture pictures into one single texture of a model?

Tags: texturing

I've met a problem while performing your steps I have a model with several materials and textures
[image: Several materials]

Thus I have had this picture before my steps

[image: Before bake]

1. Then I selected all vertexes in edit mode
2. Made UV-unwrap
3. In UV Editor made :Pack Islands
4. Baked using default settings: Properties-Render-Render Engine (Cycles)-Bske type (Normal)
5. Baked...

And after this consequence I got this:

[image: After bake]

Could you tell me the steps I made wrong?  How to put single texture on a model?